# Store Entity Framework Query to a text file to execute later

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

I need to create a function that stores the queries that are executed to do the basic CRUD operations using entity framework.

```
using(var db = new DBContext)
{
   var query = from evnt in db.Evnts where evnt.User.Id == 1
   db.Evnts.Remove(query)
}
```

I need to save this function to a text file when the user is offline, so that I can update the database once the user is online. How can I achieve this?

```
var sql = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery)query)
            .ToTraceString();
```

I tried this but it doesn't work if the item is not an IQueryable object

```
Opened connection at 12/4/2019 5:06:44 AM +00:00
Started transaction at 12/4/2019 5:06:44 AM +00:00
INSERT [dbo].[Evnts]([EvntTitle], [StartDate], [EndDate], [EvntType], [Rerr], [Note], [UserId], [Location], [ContactId], [Discriminator])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, NULL, NULL, @7)
SELECT [EventId]
FROM [dbo].[Events]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [EventId] = scope_identity()
-- @0: 'test' (Type = String, Size = 50)
-- @1: '12/4/2019 5:06:37 AM' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @2: '12/4/2019 5:06:37 AM' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @3: 'Task' (Type = String, Size = 128)
-- @4: 'True' (Type = Boolean)
-- @5: '' (Type = String, Size = 500)
-- @6: '6' (Type = Int32)
-- @7: 'Task' (Type = String, Size = 128)
-- Executing at 12/4/2019 5:06:44 AM +00:00
-- Completed in 20 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Committed transaction at 12/4/2019 5:06:44 AM +00:00
Closed connection at 12/4/2019 5:06:44 AM +00:00
```

Update : I was able to get this stored in a text file, how can I run this to update the database.

Comment: My first hunch would be expression tree. Maybe you can have a look at that.